# How to describe an image file on javascript file through codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter

I’m new using codeigniter. I using codeigniter 2.X. I have some question regarding basic course of codeigniter.

1. What the best suggestion for folder location of our external **css**/ **js** /**image**/another ? For now, i put js/css/or another file on the root, i.e `site url/css`
2. How to describe path of image on css and javascript file ? On php its easily that just use `<?php echo base_url(); ?>` but how in css and javascript?

Both question, I need for the best and experience answer because the answer will be my knowledge base for using codeigniter.

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

Store your css/js/image in assets folder or as u want

```
/www
/code_igniter
    /application
    /assets
        +img
        +css
        +js
    /controllers
    /system
```

then use it in your view as including it

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href='<?php echo base_url()?>assets/css/mystyle.css'>
<script type="text/javascript" src='<?php echo base_url()?>assets/js/myjs.js'></script>
```

into your `.htacess` file add this code

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]
```

put `.htaccess` file outside the application folder

Comment: Would you please to tell me what the function of I put htacess on codeigniter folder ? And what the funtion about code of htacess above? Thank you